# Removing noises (small white patches) from a binary image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, noise-reduction

Below is result of segmentation of an image featuring blood vessels:

[image: blood vessels segmentation]

I need to remove the separate white pixels (noises) to end up with only the true pixels creating the blood vessels. How can I do this using MATLAB?

I've tried using `medfilter` as many papers said, but the result I obtained is not what I wanted.

Comment: The kernel size for `medfilter` needs to match the maximum size blobs you intend to remove. The default kernel size is 3x3, which only removes 1x1 pixel noise.

Comment: Patrick Roberts, thank you for answering my question. Can I ask you to explain more how can I know the maximum size of the blobs? since I'm new to the subject of image segmentation and preprocessing it's still hard for me to address this problem. Thank you again

Comment: Determining the maximum size of the blobs is part of your problem statement. You need to determine an acceptable threshold at which you differentiate between "noise" and "data".

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: try to find connected components and keep only which take > 10% of image size